# grails & MVC form architecture - use two actions per form .. a general industry pattern?

Tags: model-view-controller, grails

I'm a bit new to Grails and also Web MVC in general.  Looking at the scaffolded grails architecture, and extending that to building forms for an end-user web app, the pattern seems to be to devote two actions to a page that collects form data: the first to display the page, including any errors from previous submits, and the second to act on the data on submission, producing errors and a) returning to the first action as need be, or b) going on to a successor action/controller if no errors.

My question is, is this an "industry standard" type of pattern ... should it be?

Or might one alternatively make this work via one action in some cases ... or perhaps use 3 actions in other cases, e.g. perhaps one for the display of errors?

P.S.  Please ignore my comment below; I updated this question quite a bit

--------- for purposes of discussion and for those reading with a Web MVC background but not a grails background, here's the grails generated code (version 1.3.7)

```
def create = {
    def personInstance = new Person()
    personInstance.properties = params
    return [personInstance: personInstance]
}

def save = {
    def personInstance = new Person(params)
    if (personInstance.save(flush: true)) { // my additon: save causes validation to be performed against user specified constraints, returning true or false
        flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'person.label', default: 'Person'), personInstance.id])}"
        redirect(action: "show", id: personInstance.id)
    }
    else {
        render(view: "create", model: [personInstance: personInstance])
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the first action is for the user to land on the form and display the page, and the second action is to handle the "submit".   Is this all very standard ... using two actions this way, or are sometimes 3 actions used?  Or a single action?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say at this point it is industry standard.  Most of the Java web frameworks implement the idea of forwarding to the view rather than exposing the view technology by having a user navigate to a .jsp/.gsp/.html page.  I believe this became more of a standard when scriptlets (java code in the view) started to become a huge anti-pattern.  At that point, the only way to get data into the view was to get the data on the server, then forward that data to the view.

Even when we redirect, we redirect to an action on the server which forwards to the view.  So to your point, you thoughts are accurate that you'll generally have at least 2 actions.  Although, depending on the complexity of your application, you'll end up with a handful more.  For example, your scaffolded CRUD will contain 4 (index, save, update, delete)

Comment: Thanks for the history on scriplets and overloading pages with code.  I still have a few questions: could this be done with one action ... why/why not?  Please note too I'm not talking about the standard CRUD stuff in this question (I just based my stuff off of Grails to start with).  I'm trying to understand "forms" architecture more, where someone needs to fill in and submit some information to a site (that might never be edited at all, or never edited in any close resemblance to the way in which it was entered, in much different areas of the site).

Comment: You're getting into an area that isn't quite going to fit with StackOverflow's Q&A style.  Architecture of a system isn't quite so cut and dry.

You could do everything with one action so long as you used some logic in that action to determine what needed to be done.  But I'd highly advise against that design.

Again, there are other sites including other Stackoverflow communities that are geared more towards design questions.  I'd look into those.  This site is more about technical questions that generally have a more black & white type of response.